# How to loop over kubectl's node list, echoing each node name?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I want to be loop through the node names from the
`kubectl get nodes` command and echo the names in `Bash`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`kubectl` provides various filters under `-o` flag. you can see the list using `kubectl --help`.  One of the ways is to loop over it using for loop.

```
for node in $(kubectl get nodes -o name);
do
  echo "     Node Name: ${node##*/}"
  echo "Type/Node Name: ${node}"
  echo  
done
```

> -o, --output='': Output format. One of:
> json|yaml|wide|name|custom-columns=...|custom-columns-file=...|go-template=...|go-template-file=...|jsonpath=...|jsonpath-file=...